# Multiple htaccess statements on one line

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to write two or more statements on one line in an .htaccess file for Apache. For example

```
ErrorDocument 403 "test"
ErrorDocument 404 "test2"
```

Would ideally become the following if the end statement character was ";"

```
ErrorDocument 403 "test";ErrorDocument 404 "test2"
```

This isn't for readability purposes it is for parsing.

***Update** I've also tried the following which might help you think outside the box:

```
<directory>ErrorDocument 403 "test"</directory><directory>ErrorDocument 404 "test2"</directory>
```

Comment: how is splitting on semcolon different to splitting on line break? Annd, no line breaks are required: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html#syntax

Comment: No, thats not possible.

Answer (score 2):

***"No."***  That's the long-and-short of it. Apache obliges you to use the "newline" character where for some reason you seem to be intent on using a semicolon.